# Laptop overheating on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, laptop, nvidia-optimus, overheating

I have dell inspiron q17r with two graphic cards and I noticed that it is overheating. I installed bumblebee, jupiter and flashblock, I followed [this](http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-fix-over-heating-of-laptops-with-switchable-graphics/) but it still got to even 74C. 
[Here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting) I found something:

> Power management relies on ACPI, disabling ACPI renders bbswitch
>   unusable. Be sure that your kernel boot parameters do not contain on
>   of the options noacpi, pci=noacpi, acpi=off.

And I changed it to pci=noacpi because without it didn't even started.. I followed [this](http://goof848.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/how-to-setup-ubuntu-11-10-on-a-inspiron-17r-n7110/) but in point 4. I installed bumblebee instead.

What should I do?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered getting a [cooling pad](http://www.restockit.com/cooler-master-usa-x-slim-notepal-cooler-%28r9nbcxsligp%29.html) for your laptop? My brother's laptop has the same problem, but a cooling pad does a good job of preventing overheating.

Comment: yeah I got it but it's ridiculous solution, don't You think? It should work correctly without cooling pad..
@Qasim - it's not very helpfull to my problem.

Comment: As someone here said:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/74246/can-i-mess-up-my-hardware-with-acpi-off-or-acpi-noirq
it's not very healthy to run on such high level. If I could get my ubuntu to work without acpi=noacpi it would be great. So..anyone knows any solution to that? :P

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `pci=noacpi` to `pci=acpi`- basically it should enable [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface). (src: from edit on your post:)

> EDIT: So I changed pci=noacpi to pci=acpi and.. it's working great :)
>   don't know what are the consequences but the temperature is lower than
>   on windows :)

I think this was simply a case you misread [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting#i-dont-get-any-power-saving) :)